# Who writes date and time into log file?

Tags: logging, go

I wrote this little function to log into file

```
func logMessage(message string) {
    file, err := os.OpenFile("my.log", O_CREATE|O_RDWR|O_APPEND, 0)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    log.SetOutput(file)
    log.Println(message)
}
```

But what I do not understand is why

```
logMessage("foo")
logMessage("bar")
```

write this content into file:

```
2017/03/21 03:34:42 foo
2017/03/21 03:34:42 bar
```

Can I write without `YYYY/MM/DD HH:II:SS`?

Comment: "... logger writes to standard error and prints the date and time of each logged message...."   https://golang.org/pkg/log/

Comment: if you are going to open and close the file with every log statement (which is a really bad idea) why would you even use the logger module at all?  Just `fmt.Fprintln(file,msg)` and be done with it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a logger instance with its flags set to `0`:

```
log.New(dest, "", 0)
```

References:

- https://golang.org/pkg/log/#pkg-constants

Demo: https://play.golang.org/p/ssVaeS9YAu